# Function that accepts an int, a list, or a tuple and returns true if it is a list

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make my own function that receives an int, a list, or a tuple. The function returns true if it is a list else a false if it not a list. But I keep getting none or false when I try to run it.

```
def int_list_tuple(value):
  if value==list:
     return True
  if value !=list:
     return False

print(int_list_tuple(6))
print(int_list_tuple([6, 7, 9]))
print(int_list_tuple((6, 2)))
```

Comment: Don't check if the value is the type `list`, but if the value`s `type` is the type `list`. Also, what should the function do if it gets, say, a `str`? Also return `False`, or something else? `None` or an Exception?

Comment: @TimRoberts or, alternatively, `if type(value) is list` depending on the precise semantics you want (include subclasses or not)

Comment: Please in the future try to do some basic research before posting a question like this. Simply googling "how to check the type of an object" in Python brings the linked duplicate up as the first hit.

Comment: well I know how to check the type of an object though it literally print(type()). Or am I wrong, how am I suppose to know. If I knew why would I ask for help?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a function for that
isinstance(obj, list)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it this way, which isn't recommended at all for good programming practices... (You should really be asking yourself why you need to do this.)

```
def list_check(value):
  if isinstance(value, list):
     return True
  return False

print(list_check(6))
print(list_check([6, 7, 9]))
print(list_check((6, 2)))
```

Another not-as-durable way of doing this is like in the linked duplicate question.

```
print(type(6) is list)
print(type([6, 7, 9]) is list)
print(type ((6, 2)) is list)
```

The problem is that if you are needing to check for type, while sometimes unavoidable, should be avoided.

Comment: Well I am making basic ideas to further understand specific concepts. What would you say is "good programming practice"

Comment: There are interesting lessons here.  It's quite reasonable to have a function that accepts int, list or tuple, but in general you should be able to treat ANY sequence object identically.  That is, you could check for int, but otherwise just iterate through whatever you were given.  You shouldn't need to care about list vs tuple vs iterator.